# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Dynamodb

Tags: sql, hashmap, amazon-dynamodb, illegalargumentexception

I have the following code:-

```
    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS("12"));

    ScrapCategoryDO myObject = new ScrapCategoryDO();
    myObject.setCategoryName("Iron");
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<ScrapCategoryDO> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<ScrapCategoryDO>()
            //.withHashKeyValues(myObject)
            .withFilterExpression("UnitPrice < :val1")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

    List<ScrapCategoryDO> latestReplies = mapper.query(ScrapCategoryDO.class, queryExpression);
    Log.d(TAG, "Number of categories = "+latestReplies.size());
    for (ScrapCategoryDO reply : latestReplies) {
        Log.d(TAG,"category name = "+reply.getCategoryName()+", unit price = "+ reply.getUnitPrice());
    }
```

And I am getting the following error on with .withHashKeyValues(myObject) as commented. I want to know how can I query the entire table without any filter criteria/condition or so? I tried :-

```
     DynamoDBQueryExpression<ScrapCategoryDO> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<ScrapCategoryDO>();
```

But still I was getting the same error.

W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query
W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.processKeyConditions(DynamoDBMapper.java:2424)
W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.createQueryRequestFromExpression(DynamoDBMapper.java:2386)
W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:2169)
W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:2130)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.rohitsingla.scrapman.MyActivity.FindAllScrapCategories(MyActivity.java:207)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.rohitsingla.scrapman.MyActivity.access$000(MyActivity.java:26)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.rohitsingla.scrapman.MyActivity$3.run(MyActivity.java:164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **scan API** to get all the records from DynamoDB table. Here is the sample code.

Query API can't be used without the key attributes.

**Sample code:-**

```
ScanResultPage<yourModelClass> yourModelClassResultPage = null;
do {
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    if (yourModelClassResultPage != null) {
        scanExpression.setExclusiveStartKey(yourModelClassResultPage.getLastEvaluatedKey());
    }
    yourModelClassResultPage = dynamoDBMapper.scanPage(yourModelClass.class, scanExpression);   

} while (yourModelClassResultPage.getLastEvaluatedKey() != null);
```

[Scan API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's working. But I want to set my "CategoryName" field as a key. I am not able to update my table by going to console. need help in that.

Comment: If you have defined CategoryName as key, it can't be updated once inserted. Would appreciate if you can accept the answer and open new question if there is a new problem for everyone's benefit and brevity.